# Target the closest element to a link on click

Tags: jquery

I currently have this markup for a custom accordion I am using;

```
<dl class="acc">
    <dd>
        <a href="#panel1">Panel1 Title</a>
        <div id="panel1" class="content">CONTENT</div>
    </dd>

    <dd>
        <a href="#panel2">Panel2 Title</a>
        <div id="panel2" class="content">CONTENT</div>
    </dd>
</dl>
```

and I'm using this little jQuery snippet to add a class of "active" to the div when the preceding link is clicked;

```
$('.acc dd').click(function(){
    $(this).find('a').removeAttr("href");
    $(this).find('div.content').toggleClass('active');
});
```

which worked fine, as the content of the div was just an image, but now there is text in there and when a user clicks on it the accordion pane is closed because I'm using the `dd` as the selector.

Is there a way that I can target the link and then ONLY apply the `active` class to the div that immediately follows it?

The markup above is the same for every accordion pane too if that helps.

Comment: When an anchor is clicked do you not have to remove the active class from any div that may already have the class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
$('.acc a').click(function(){
   $('.active').removeClass('active');
   $(this).removeAttr("href");
   $(this).next('div.content').toggleClass('active');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you can target that link that was clicked and also remove the class from any other div with the `active` class:

```
$('.acc dd').click(function(){
    $(this).removeAttr("href"); //not sure why you're doing this
    $(this).closest( 'dl' ).find('div.content').not( $(this).next() ).removeClass( 'active' );
    $(this).next().addClass( 'active' );
});
```

Why are you removing the `href`? Will you not click the link again?